# "which" command throws "not found" at the end

Tags: shell, terminal

I was playing with "which" and "echo" commands and I got this strange "not found" at the end of some outputs when using "which", "echo" shows no issue.

```
➜  ~ which $HOME
/Users/rocker not found
➜  ~ echo $HOME
/Users/rocker
➜  ~ which $ZSH
/Users/rocker/.oh-my-zsh not found
➜  ~ echo $ZSH
/Users/rocker/.oh-my-zsh
➜  ~
```

It doesn't happen when I use it with less or cat

```
➜  ~ which less
/usr/bin/less
➜  ~ which cat
/bin/cat
➜  ~
```

My shell is .zsh in a mac.
Not sure if it affects but I have oh-my-zsh installed.
Hope you guys can give me a hand.

Comment: Why do you expect passing `which` the name of a directory (or a non-executable file, or a fully qualified path) to do anything useful?

Comment: More to the point, though, this is simply off topic here. Stack Overflow is only for questions about _software development_. For questions about how to use your shell as an end user, see [unix.se].

Comment: Sorry about that, new in this community. will look Unix & Linux. Thx for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [man page of `which`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which) this command:

> Name
>
> which - shows the full path of (shell) commands.

The command do not index and show all the files in the filesystem and this is the reason you get those results.

Comment: The man page is the wrong documentation for the zsh-builtin version of which; it covers only the external-binary version.